# Connect to iBeacon

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

I can scan for iBeacons with:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {

  }
}
```

let suppose I get the following beacons after scanning

```
Beacon 1: major:1 minor:5 uuid:xxx
Beacon 2: major:1 minor:6 uuid:xxx
Beacon 3: major:1 minor:7 uuid:xxx
```

After the scan I want to connect to beacon 2 and change its characteristics.

I know I can use CoreBluetooth to scan and connect to a Bluetooth device and change its characteristics, but the problem is how can I identify which device is beacon 2 via Core Bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot obtain any information that directly relates a `CLBeacon` to a  `CBPeripheral`.

Typically the beacon's GATT service will expose a "device name" characteristic that you can display to the user to allow them to select the device to be configured from a list.

As David pointed in the comments, any such GATT service will be vendor specific, or it may not even exist, with the beacon being configured through some other method, such as USB. Even where a GATT service is provided it may be disabled through configuration or only active for a limited period after initial power-on.

There is no generic "configure an iBeacon" service defined.

Comment: To add to Paul's answer, not all beacons have connectable GATT services.  Some manufacturers do provide this for configuration, but you cannot use CoreLocation APIs.  You must use CoreBluetooth APIs.  And the specifics of how you do so are all vendor-specific.  Ask your beacon manufacturer if they have docs for a public config GATT service. You cannot correlate beacon detections to CoreBluetooth devices.  Apple unfortunately blocks this.

Comment: what i get is there is no way to relate CLBeacon with CBPeripheral, in order to relate both i need to connect all beacons and check one by one and then identify the right beacon because the beacon i am using also exposes its major/minor/uuid via gatt. but this approach is useless if i have more beacons like 20+

Comment: As David said, it depends on your beacon; some may expose a useful name via their GATT service.  There is no standard way of configuring beacons

Comment: Another approach that will work is to advertise custom payload agter certain interval with uuid , major,minor and do both CLBeacon and CBPeripheral scanning, when user clicks on specific ibeacon connect it via CBPeripheral

Comment: yes; exactly; the GATT service is something you have to define (if you are making your own beacon device) or something that the manufacturer will have defined.

Comment: @Paulw11 i know uuid, major and minor is exposed via gatt service, i have verified it with android and i know the relevant characteristics to read.

Comment: Then you should be able to write some simple code that can discover the service, connect to the beacon, read the major/minor/uuid and then disconnect.  Execution of that won't take long; no more than a second or two

Comment: Connecting to a beacon is not a good option if you have a list of like 200 or 100 beacons.I think it is good to broadcast two types of beacons 1. ibeacon and 2.custom beacon(contains uuid,major,minor and broadcasted at certain interval and will be scan-able with Corebluetooth) and when i want to connect to specific i beacon connect via equivalent  CBPeripheral.

Comment: And yes i am working with my own beacon so i can do firmware level changes too.